# Meteor each loop within template

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

So I'm looking for some understanding on how templates and such work.

I've movie.html file with a template named movies in it, with a `movie.js` helper that returns a collection.

**Movies Template**

```
<template name="movies">
   <li>{{title}}</li>
</template>
```

**JS Helpers**

```
Template.body.helpers({
  movie: function () {
    return Movies.find({});
    }
  });
```

Now I've another template that does a bunch of other things but one of them is to iterate over this list and display it.

**List Template**

```
<template name="list">
    <ul>
        {{#each movie}}
            {{> movies}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

In this situation the list doesn't popular with the data.

However, if I move the contents of the list template outside of a template and just on the `main.html` it works great!

This is how I used to use it but I've started to use [Houston Admin Package](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin) which uses `Iron:Router` so I've moved the main (and only) page to a template for routing purposes, which breaks my looping list.

I'm sure I'm missing something minor but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `{{#each movie}}` helper on the list Template so change the `Template.helper` to the `list` template

```
Template.list.helpers({
  movie: function () {
    return Movies.find({});
    }
  });
```

We are you calling this `<template name="list">` on the `body` tag? you have something like this.

```
<body>
 {{> list}}
</body>
```

Or you have something like this.

```
<template name="layout">
 {{> yield}} <!-- since you are mentioning iron:route package -->
</template>
```

Or you have a route to that list template? localhost:3000/lists

```
Router.route('/movie-lists', function () {
  this.render('lists')
});
```

On whatever of this 3 cases, you should point the [helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) into the template where you are calling it (in this case list template)

Comment: Changing the helper worked, it never even crossed my mind that needed to be updated! And I'm using the below to display the page `Router.map(function(){
    this.route('list', {path: '/'} );
});`